# cycloid of a unit-speed circle

Tags: multivariable-calculus, intuition, parametric

In one of the lectures of the MIT OCW Multivariable Calculus course, the professor introduces the parametric equation of a cycloid in the plane, where $a$ is the radius of the circle that creates it, as:

$$x(t)=a\theta-asin(\theta)$$
$$y(t)=a-acos(\theta)$$

He then simplified the parametric by giving the circle that creates the cycloid a radius of $a=1$ and unit speed. The professor explained that by giving the circle unit speed, we can just replace the angle, which we had previously used as the parameter, with time. So the parametrization simplifies to:
$$x(t)=t-sin(t)$$
$$y(t)=1-cos(t)$$
However, I don't understand the intuition that allowed him to immediately know that replacing $\theta$ with $t$ sets the parent circle at unit speed. Is there a way to think about the substitution that can give me some sort of intuition on why this is true?

*(edited to reflect actual conceptual issue)*

Comment: That parameterization is not unit speed.

Comment: @Tyler Could you explain why? My confusion is basically just that--whether or not the parameterization is actually legit and if it is intuitively obvious/extendable. However, I was under the impression that in the case of a unit cycloid, given the computation that I detailed in my question, the parameterization *does* indeed give unit speed.

Comment: You have a function $(x,y) = \phi(t)$, whose velocity is $\phi'(t)$. The speed is $\| \phi'(t)\|$, which you can check is not identically $1$.

Comment: @Tyler Ah yes, you're completely right--it looks like I was thinking about the issue I was having in a totally erroneous way. I've edited the question to reflect the real conceptual problem that I'm having. Thanks so much!

Comment: The definition of a radian is precisely that it is, in a sense, the arc-length/unit-speed parameterization of a circle. To be more precise, given a circle of radius 1, a radian $\theta$ is _defined_ to be the angle such that the arc it subtends has a length $\theta$. This is why he can just throw $\theta$ in an know that the parent circle is unit-speed parameterized.

Comment: @Tyler Ah, that makes a ton of sense--because a radian is defined as arc length/radius, if the radius is $1$ a radian $\theta$ is the arc length as well, so replacing $\theta$ with $t$ gives the circle unit speed. Thanks!